# What do you think of this visual category theory tool? See any issues? Would you use it?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, math-software, computer-assisted-proofs, categorical-logic

The idea behind it is that every category theoretical definition is made with visual diagrams.  One reason this is good is that we don't have to do as much language processing which is hard IMO.

Here is a mockup of the design in mspaint.

[image]

You can probably already figure out what it means.  The green portion is the implication part of the definition, the rest is the conditional part.  Namely, that diagram can easily be translated to:

> Given a functor $F : C \to D$, $F$ is **faithful** if for any $f,g : X\to Y$ in $C$, if $F(f) = F(g) $ in $D$, then $f = g$.

So the idea is that any diagram asserted is implicitly asserted to be commutative, so all diagrams commute.

You can apply diagrammed definitions / theorems to a diagram that you draw, and thus do the *some of the work* of a mathematician quicker and in a format that you can share with others, in a pretty-looking form.

Of course one tool it will have is diagram chasing, which after I get the app to understand these diagrams, should be straightforward enough.

It will be a desktop application written in PyQt5.  Would you use it in your work or as a notetaking or teaching tool?

Asserted existence arrows will be done with a dotted arrow.  I will not support special types of arrows such as $\twoheadrightarrow$, but instead prefer the word *epimorphism* drawn next to the arrow.

Comment: How would you *prove* something with this? Here's a proof that right adjoints preserve limits:If $F\dashv U$ then $$\begin{align}\mathsf{Hom}(-,U\mathsf{Lim}D)&\cong\mathsf{Hom}(F-,\mathsf{Lim}D)\\&\cong\mathsf{Lim}(I\mapsto\mathsf{Hom}(F-,DI))\\&\cong\mathsf{Lim}(I\mapsto\mathsf{Hom}(-,UDI))\\&\cong\mathsf{Hom}(-,\mathsf{Lim}(U\circ D))\end{align}$$ then use Yoneda. How would you present this?

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to get from your image that $F(f)=F(g)$. This just looks like two parallel morphisms to me. Anyway, this example has nothing to do specifically with category theory-if you draw points instead of arrows, it would just give the definition of injective function. So it's hard to see what, exactly, you're thinking of doing.

Comment: @KevinCarlson by default every asserted diagram commutes, so if two arrows are parallel they are asserted to commute.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond Did you end up building this thing? Contact me paul.hans.fischer.94@gmail.com

Comment: @user can't get that email to work :D

Comment: Paul,

Thank you for your interest.  I have one half-working prototype in Python (not useable yet), and am currently porting the app over to Qt / C++ for sake of graphics speed (nested nodes, arrow dependencies, etc become laggy in PyQt5).
Are you interested in helping develop it with me?
Also, what would be a fair price per licensed copy?  I'm thinking anywhere from $5 - $50 USD.

Comment: That would include a customer seat in our Jira forums (issue reporting software).
I'm bringing back some original features I had and *not* doing things via graph transformations.  Instead think of how Geogebra does things.  So there will be a Functor class in C++ and so on...

If you'd like to stay updated, please let me know!

Comment: I said 6 months ago that I would have it ready, but this kind of software is extremely difficult to write and there are no references on how to do it.  I was at a few points going to connect with Lean Prover and / or Coq IDE, but have decided not to.  The only dependency then will be a backend of MkTeK which the user will be directed (via a link) to install.  Otherwise you can only use it in Unicode mode.  Which is okay too!

Reach me on MSE with a chat ping or email me at `enjoysmath`  (google mail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One reason this is good is that we don't have to do as much language processing which is hard IMO.

"We" being the developers of the software, or the users of the software? Because:

(a) in general, humans are language-processing machines, which is why games like 'Charades' and 'Pictionary' can be amusing; it's often more challenging to convey information precisely using imagery than it is by using language directly.

(b) there are many humans (such as myself) who regularly find spatially-based information more difficult to comprehend than syntactically-based information (which is why i find category theory's diagram-chasing to be challenging, and which is why algebraic topology helps me develop my 'visual intuition', so to speak). Just because many people find e.g. learning by watching a video to be easier than learning by reading an article (which i don't), don't assume this is universally (or even mostly) true.

It might be useful to read up on the history of the success of 'visual programming languages' compared to the general ongoing success of text-based programming languages; there are reasons why visually-based programming languages keep being proposed, yet haven't become the dominant paradigm.

Comment: All good points.  However, can your brain automatically parse this with zero learning time?  http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/cgi-bin/SeeTPTP?Category=Problems&Domain=ALG&File=ALG337-1.p

Comment: With this visual language, understanding it requires no 100+ page datasheet of a weird language such as in Coq or Isabelle,  though this isn't a proof assistant tool per se.

Comment: No, my brain can't. But then, proof assistants such as Isabelle/HOL and Coq use language that *disambiguates* all the ambiguities that are present in visual representations. In doing so, they've shown just how much implicit topic-specific knowledge is involved in the practice of mathematics - and this is a good thing, since much of the development of mathematics has proceeded by challenging assumptions.

Comment: For example: by visual inspection, one might reasonably assume that [the Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), being everywhere continuous, is everywhere (or almost everywhere) differentiable, yet the latter is not in fact the case.

Comment: Another example: by visual inspection, i feel it's not immediately obvious that [the topologist's since curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) is connected but not locally connected or path-connected.

Comment: @EnjoysMath You realize that if you tried to reproduce all those formulas "visually", instead of 23 pages you'd likely have something like ~500. Also TPTP is a standardized format for *fully* automatic theorem provers. It's meant to be generated by programs typically, not written by humans. In fact, I'm pretty confident that file *was* generated by a program. In other words, that file was neither written by a human nor intended to be consumed by a human. This is like pointing at the intermediate assembly code a compiler produces and saying "Look! Programming languages are incomprehensible!"

Comment: I do not think it is wise to "accept" answers so fast. You haven't even waited half a day for other answers to come, mine for example. People live in different time zones or are busy with other matters. Give them time to read your question.

Comment: @magma: Despite being the beneficiary of the "accepted answer" points in this instance, I agree with you; my experience with the SE process is that it's biased towards people in timezones with larger numbers of speakers of the language in which a question is asked. I'm in Australia, and it can be difficult to gain site points when questions get asked after I go to bed, and answers get accepted before I get up!